# Next js Image remote src (удаленные изображения в NextJs c разными протоколами)

Tags: изображения, nextjs

я использую в приложении NextJs удаленные изображения с разными протоколами (http и https),в разных секциях выводятся картинки из разных тестовых API, в документации сказано что в next.config.js можно указать только один протокол. Можно ли все таки получать картинки с разными протоколами ?